# Simultaneous scanning of barcodes and text(OCR) in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ocr, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I have a scanner app where we scan the barcodes and Text on the same camera. I have done this in xamarin with the help of Xamarin.Firebase.IOS.MlKit.
In this when the camera is open, we do continous capturing of image frames, and send the captured image for barcode detection and OCR recognition seperately.

```
 public override void DidOutputSampleBuffer(AVCaptureOutput captureOutput, CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer, AVCaptureConnection connection)
            {
                lastRunTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
                if (lastRunTime - lastAnalysisTime > scanIntervalInMs)
                {
                    lastAnalysisTime = lastRunTime;
                    try
                    {
                        var image = GetImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer);
                        if(image == null) return;
                        var visionImage = new VisionImage(image) {Metadata = metadata };
                        releaseSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer);
                        if(isScanningBarcode)
                        {
                            DetectBarcodeActionAsync(visionImage);
                            isScanningBarcode = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isScanningBarcode = true;
                            DetectTextActionAsync(visionImage);
                        }
                      
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                    }
                }
                releaseSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer);
            }
```

//Barcode detection

```
private async void DetectBarcodeActionAsync(VisionImage image)
 {
      VisionBarcode[] barcodes = await barcodeDetector.DetectAsync(image);
 }
```

//OCR

```
private async void DetectTextActionAsync(VisionImage image)
{
     VisionText txt = await textRecognizer.ProcessImageAsync(image);
}
```

This runs properly. But our app is used in package scanning to scan address labels (names of the recipient) and barcodes. So, when the barcodes are damaged or curved/skewed, this MLKit barcode fails to scan such barcodes, and this is quite frustrating for the clients.

Is there a way we can improve upon the MLKIt barcode scanner to scan such damaged barcodes.
I tried the same with some premium scanners like ScanBot and SCandit demo apps, which were able to scan the damaged barcodes quite easily. I had a talk with ScanBot customer service, but they do not provide SIMULTANEOUS barcode and OCR scanning. I am also looking in this ScanDit SDK to accomplish the same.

Can anyone suggest some premium scanners for xamarin app which scans barcodes and OCR in one go. OR any improvements which can be made to existing MLKit scanner so that it can scan damaged/skewed barcodes.

Comment: what is `barcodeDetector.DetectAsync` - is that your own method, or a method from the library?

Comment: a method from xamarin.firebase.IOS.MlKit

Comment: But how can a barcode which can't display fully be scanned for a result?